# Vibration not working in some api levels

Tags: android, vibration

I have utils class for vibration function its working in some apis but not working in another

api 17 is working

api 24 not working

could any one guide me why this code not working
Note I took right permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

My Class

```
public class VibrateUtils {


    public static void VibrateMethod(Context mContext , String PassedValue) {

        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Start without a delay
        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
        // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
        long[] pattern = {0, 500, 1000};

        switch (PassedValue){

            case "1":
                // Start without a delay
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> First time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                pattern = new long[]{0, 500, 1000};
                break;

            case "2":
                // Start without a delay
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds  --> First time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> Second time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                pattern = new long[]{0, 500, 500 , 500 , 500 };
                break;

            case "3":
                // Start without a delay
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds  --> First time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> Second time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> Third time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                pattern = new long[]{0, 500, 1000 , 500 , 1000  , 500 , 1000};
                break;

            case "4":
                // Start without a delay
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds  --> First time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> Second time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> Third time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds   --> Fourth time
                // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                pattern = new long[]{0, 500, 1000 , 500 , 1000  , 500 , 1000 , 500 , 1000};
                break;

        }



        // The '0' here means to repeat indefinitely
        // '0' is actually the index at which the pattern keeps repeating from (the start)
        // To repeat the pattern from any other point, you could increase the index, e.g. '1'
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(pattern, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        }else{
            v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even the answer is not related to development but I would like answer my question , the reason why vibrate wastn't working that the vibration intensity for Notification was off

[image]

Reference https://android.stackexchange.com/a/158261